# I want to replace Object with anotherone in game How can i do that?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get this code to work and replace one object in the map that is broken with a new one that I will assign to it. but I don't know why I get this error

> Assets\Replacement.cs(31,63): error CS0117: 'Quaternion' does not contain a definition for 'Indentity'

this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Replacement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Broken_Table;
    public GameObject Table;
    private bool used = false;

    void Start()
    {

}

    void Update()
{

    if (!used && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {

        Replace(Broken_Table, Table);
        Debug.Log("Replaced");
        used = true;
  }

}
    void Replace(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2)
{

        Instantiate(obj2, obj1.transform.position, Quaternion.indentity);
        Destroy(obj1);

    }
}
```

Comment: You have misspelled `identity` as `indentity`.

Comment: i just realized. thank you but the problem is when I press on the object nothing changes

Comment: You haven't included any details regarding that issue so I can't help you there. You gave an error message and I gave you the fix for that error.

Comment: so when I click on the object in-game it destroys itself but doesn't replace with the other object I want it to replace with. and it gives this error:

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
Replacement.Replace (UnityEngine.GameObject obj1, UnityEngine.GameObject obj2) (at Assets/Replacement.cs:32)
Replacement.Update () (at Assets/Replacement.cs:23)

Comment: You need the script to instantiate the new one then destroy. While destroy is not immediate. What if it was bored and did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing "Quaternion.indentity" by "obj1.transform.rotation"

Comment: it is working but it clones the replacing object infinite times on the Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the data type does not contain a referenced member.
Quaternion.indentity should be changed to Quaternion.identity.The object is destroyed and you should re-instantiate it.

```
if (!used && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    GameObject broken_Table = Instantiate(Broken_Table) as GameObject;
    GameObject table = Instantiate(Table) as GameObject;
    Replace(broken_Table, table);
    Debug.Log("Replaced");
    used = true;
}
```

Comment: i press and nothing happens. because this is a phone game should I replace if (!used && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)). with something that has to do with phone buttons?

Comment: @Jaafar Ben Bouker When the gameobject is destroyed, the OnDestroy method of the bound script is called.
, then the object has been destroyed and cannot continue to be accessed, and an error will be reported: "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'LoadingAssert' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it". You need to re-instantiate the object such as using the method: GameObject.Instantiate ();